# Integrating Kerberos authentication on Apache with a Git server

Tags: httpd, kerberos, git

First time asking a question here so I hope I'm in the right place to do so.
I've also searched for similar problems on here, but couldn't find anything quite as similar.

Here's my problem. We currently have a git server (using Gitorious) that is currently working well. I was asked to add an additional layer of security to the web interface by authenticating with Kerberos. So I went ahead and configured Apache to prompt for user authentication using mod_auth_kerb whenever a user attempts to go to the web interface. Everything works great as far as the web interface is concerned. However, when trying to git pull/push anything from the command line, it fails horribly.

Here is relevant information:

In my apache configuration, I tried the 2 following methods, both yielding the same results:

```
<Directory /home/git/active/>

        AuthName "Restricted Access Kerberos"
        AuthType Kerberos
        Krb5Keytab  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.keytab
        KrbAuthRealms TEST.COMPANY.COM
        KrbMethodNegotiate On
        KrbMethodK5Passwd On
       require valid-user

</Directory>

<Location />

        AuthName "Restricted Access Kerberos"
        AuthType Kerberos
        Krb5Keytab  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.keytab
        KrbAuthRealms TEST.COMPANY.COM
        KrbMethodNegotiate On
        KrbMethodK5Passwd On
        require valid-user

</Location>
```

The following is what appears when trying to pull from the command line:

```
== Gitorious: ==========================================================

Access denied or wrong repository path

========================================================================

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Seen in gitorious_auth.log:

```
I, [2014-01-17 15:02:47#8854]  INFO -- : Connection from "192.168.50.11 59109 22" (beauclaira): git-receive-pack 'sysadmin/puppet.git'
I, [2014-01-17 15:02:47#8854]  INFO -- : Access denied or bad repository path for "beauclaira": "git-receive-pack 'sysadmin/puppet.git'"
```

And in /var/log/secure:

```
Jan 17 15:06:32 gitorious50 sshd[9286]: Accepted publickey for git from 192.168.50.11 port 59146 ssh2
Jan 17 15:06:32 gitorious50 sshd[9286]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user git by (uid=0)
Jan 17 15:06:32 gitorious50 sshd[9288]: Received disconnect from 192.168.50.11: 11: disconnected by user
Jan 17 15:06:32 gitorious50 sshd[9286]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user git
```

Did I miss something? I don't quite understand why adding this authentication in Apache is preventing users from pushing/pulling. From this I'm guessing it still passes by Apache even when pulling from the command line? Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Without knowing your SSH key configuration (any `command`, for example) it won't be possible to tell what's happening.